# neutralinojs - how to load browser extension when starting chrome mode?

Tags: neutralinojs

I have a web page and custom extension that goes with it. The extension is a normal browser extension - not a neutralinojs extension. I can load my extension from the command line (without neutrinojs) with chrome and msedge using the `--load-extension=<path-to-extension>` option. Extension and page work fine.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to achieve the same thing with neutralinojs.

I've tried passing the option via the neutralino.config.json config file [example below] and starting the page with `neu run`. The page loads, but the extension isn't loaded. Near the top of the JSON file, I specify "chrome" as the mode. I'm certain it is starting chrome.

```json
    "chrome": {
      "width": 500,
      "height": 700,
      "args": "--load-extension=C:\\project\\my-extension",
      "nativeBlockList": [
        "filesystem.*",
        "os.*"
      ]
    }
```

I also tried a more direct approach with `neutralino-win_x64.exe --chrome-args="--load-extension=C:\project\my-extension"`. It seems the JSON file isn't read in when I try it this way, and it's not clear to me how to format the other options that need to be passed to it.

How should I go about getting my custom extension loaded when starting in chrome mode? And could I also get neutralinojs to start with msedge instead of chrome with additional chrome options passed to it.